# Using OR in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is it possible to use an OR in a GROUP BY.

For example I tried:

```
GROUP BY a.id (b.id OR a.id2)
```

But this gives an error

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: This is not possible, as you have expierenced the hard way. As we don't have the slightiest clue of what you're trying to achieve, we cannot even help you. At least post a create table statement with some insert statements and an expected result set, otherwise, the question will almost certainly be closed.

Comment: I think you can't use OR in a group by expression. Also you have a miss construct `GROUP BY a.id (b.id OR a.id2)` even if it work you will need an operator between `...BY a.id` and `(b.id...` Maybe your problem is something else. Can you explain why are trying to acomplish that?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide same data and desired results.

Comment: It is most likely an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378)

Comment: No, I don't believe you can. But then you shouldn't need to either. Perhaps you could add some detail about what you want to achieve by doing so?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? With GROUP BY xyz you say: give me one result row per xyz. You could for instance group by customer to get one line per customer. So what would you expect a query like "give me one line per customer or department" suppose to produce?

Comment: this was an example, but data grouped as a.id is never null and b.id & a.id2 are either null or have a value opposite to each other

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question doesn't really make sense.  But, you can use `coalesce()` if the first value could be `NULL`:

```
GROUP BY a.id, coalesce(b.id, a.id2)
```

If these are flags (taking on values such as 0 or 1), then `or` is the same as the following:

```
GROUP BY a.id, (1 - b.id) * (1 - a.id2)
```

However, "id" is an unusual name for a field called a flag.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what i was looking for (id was just the first thing what popped into my head when typing the example).

Comment: Or to make it clear to read, you can use `case` instead - `case when (b.id or a.id2) then 1 else 0 end`.